# Cast function in SQL queries

Tags: sql

I am trying to use `CAST()` function on my `datetime` and `NULL` function.

My query is like this:

```
where  [closed_at] = '' or  Cast ([closed_at]  as datetime) > = '09-01-2011 00:00' 

     and  [class_name] in ('Job' ,'Education');
```

Comment: And ??? Do you have a question?

Comment: and if you do have a question -  please state which rdbms you are using (add a tag)

Comment: Calling `CAST` on a column is going to make it ignore any indices.  That's beside the problem of your constant time string being in an ambiguous format.  If you're lucky `closed_at` will be in a SARGable (usually ISO) format, so you can just query it with a string anyways, until you get the underlying type in the table fixed.  Also, I'm a little suspicious your boolean logic isn't doing what you want - whenever you mix `AND` and `OR`, put parenthesis around them to demonstrate intent.

Answer (score 0):

You will use IS NULL condition

```
where ([closed_at] is NULL or Cast ([closed_at] as datetime) > = '09-01-2011 00:00') and  [class_name] in ('Job' ,'Education');
```

or

```
where Cast (ISNULL([closed_at],'09-01-2011 00:00') as datetime) > = '09-01-2011 00:00') and  [class_name] in ('Job' ,'Education');
```